# Need help on SharePoint Search Rest API with POSTMAN

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-integration, postman

I am integrating Sharepoint with POSTMAN, firstly i created an app and get the client id and client secret key with which i generate the oAuth authentication and it is working perfectly fine. now when i try to search using http://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='change' i am getting {"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}.

I tried passing grant_type as client credentials still same error.

[image: PostMan]

Comment: The token you get from OAuth has an expiration date. Maybe you are trying to reach any SharePoint service with an u updated token. Please try again getting a new token and calling the service.

Comment: In addition to this, you must grant access to your client on AAD to be able to call SharePoint services and receive response.

Comment: I crosschecked my oauth token and it is still actie. In the AAD i have granted with 
Sites.FullControl.All to Sharepoint application.

Comment: Did you try calling the same web service in the Graph Explorer tool?